# Google OAuth2 One-time-code flow without Offline access on Android

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm trying to have Google Sign In on Android by implementing the [one-time-code flow](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in#enable_server-side_api_access_for_your_app). I.e. The Android app simply gets a one-time-code from Google, which then hands it to my backend server. My backend then exchanges it for an access token and gets the user's profile data.

### Problem

When I use [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) to get the one-time-code it always prompts the user for the *"Have offline access"* permission. The scope I'm currently using is "***oauth2:server:client_id::api_scope:email profile***".

Is it possible to implement the one-time-code flow with an *online* access type in order to skip the Offline access permission?

---

I also tried using the [AccountManager](https://gist.github.com/TomTasche/5665497) approach for this. It doesn't request the Offline access permission but it is a bit buggy, especially on Android L, and doesn't seem to handle account permissions correctly.